# Auto generar imagenes que estan dentro de un array

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy haciendo un menu, y para ello necesito autogenerar con un loop cada imagen, tengo la clase hecha en la que se va a incorporar la imagen, tengo todas las imagenes guardadas con un id en un array y quiero exportarlas para generarlas automaticamente en el menu. Soy principiante con los loops y para esto necesito vuestra ayuda. He estado calentandome la cabeza para conseguirlo pero se me ha complicado mucho.

```js
const sprites = {
    [0]: "radar_higher",
    [1]: "radar_level",
    [2]: "radar_lower",
    [3]: "radar_police_ped",
    [4]: "radar_wanted_radius",
    [5]: "radar_area_blip",
    [6]: "radar_centre",
    [7]: "radar_north",
    [8]: "radar_waypoint",
    [9]: "radar_radius_blip",
    [10]: "radar_radius_outline_blip",
    [11]: "radar_weapon_higher"
}

$(".blips-container").html(`
    <div class="blip-img">
        <img src="images/${sprites[1]}.png">
    </div>
`) // Esto es un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer.
```

```css
.blips-container {
    display:flex;
    align-content: start;
    gap: 5%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-overflow-style: none; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 20.2vw;
    background-color: aqua;
    left: 54%;
    top: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow-y:scroll;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
}
.blip-img {
    margin: .5vw;
    /* background-color: aqua; */
    width: 4vw;
    height: 4vw;
}
.blip-img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="blips-container">
        <div class="blip-img"></div>  
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Creo que es mas sencillo si dejas un simple arreglo de las imagenes 
const sprites = [ 
     "radar_higher",
     "radar_level",
     "radar_lower",
     "radar_police_ped",
     "radar_wanted_radius",
     "radar_area_blip",
     "radar_centre",
     "radar_north",
     "radar_waypoint",
     "radar_radius_blip",
     "radar_radius_outline_blip",
     "radar_weapon_higher" 
     ]
     
let parent = $(".blips-container")

// por cada imagen en el arreglo... 
sprites.forEach(img => {
// creas un nuevo elemento html
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add = 'blip-img'
  
// a ese elemento le agregas la imagen
  div.innerHTML = `<img src="img/${img}.png">`
  
 // y finalmente metes todo adentro del elemento padre
  parent.append(div)
})
```

Comment: hola buenos dias, me has ayudado muchisimo con esto, muchisimas gracias.